# AWS SES Cost Allocation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am using AWS SES in multiple projects and hoping to work out the monthly cost for each project.

I had a look at using the [Cost Allocation Tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/custom-tags.html) feature but it doesn't seem to support SES.  What would be the best way to track the costs of different projects?

Comment: The `Billing Dashboard` (https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home)  do not work for you?

Comment: The billing dashboard doesn't seem to give you a breakdown on the cost of each project?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to have different accounts for each project.
Projects can have it own account, or at least projects can use SES on its own account.

In this way the cost related to SES will be totally segregated per project.

Reference:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/can-i-use-multiple-aws-accounts-with-ses/

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-verify-domain-accounts-regions/

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about overall cost then set Alerts. Other option is you can use configuration set to send events in Firehose or SNS and it will contain details about everything. From there you can track who sent how many mails.
In my project use AWS organization to create multiple accounts for different projects and BU's. It helps us in many things like: Cost monitoring per account. We get separate limit for each account for sending emails. Link already shared by @Azize in other answer.